# clearpage affects the footer

Tags: footnotes, footmisc, clearpage

I have a problem that I can't solve no matter what i try. This is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[widefront, tightfn, fontsize=12.4pt]{jura}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{jurabib}
\usepackage[a4paper, nohead, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{jurabib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{sectfont}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\parindent 0pt
\parskip 0pt
\topskip 0pt

\formatpages[, ][]{article}{}{}

\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
       \setlength{\hangindent}{2em}
       \noindent
       \hb@xt@\hangindent{%
          \hss\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\hspace{.1em}}#1}
\makeatother

\deffootnote[15pt]{15pt}{15pt}{\makebox[5pt][r]{\thefootnotemark\hspace{10pt}}}

\renewcommand*{\mainmatter}{\pagenumbering{arabic}%
\voffset-1in\topmargin2cm\footskip1cm\textheight=257mm%
\hoffset-1in\oddsidemargin5.5cm\hsize13.5cm\columnwidth\hsize\linewidth\hsize\textwidth\hsize\clearpage}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \lipsum[3]
    % \maketitle

    \begin{sachverhalt}
        \lipsum[3-10]\footnote{Hello}
    \end{sachverhalt}

    \tableofcontents

    \bibliography{literatur}
    \bibliographystyle{jurabib}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \clearpage %The culprit
    \mainmatter
    \boldmath
    \chapter*{Gutachten}
        \normalsize \mdseries
        \toc{Hello}
            \lipsum[1-2]\footnote{Hello}
            \lipsum[2-5]\footnote{Hello 2}
            \lipsum[1-10]
        \sub{Hello2}
            text
        \levelup
            Hello again
\end{document}
```

The first page, table of contents and the file `sachverhalt.tex` have their pages styled with `frontmatter`. Then, for the file `gutachten.tex`, I change the page styling radically.

The problem is that if i have the `\clearpage` (marked in the code), the footnote line on the **first** page in the `gutachten.tex` file is incorrect (see picure below)

[image: Bad footnote position]

If i remove the `\clearpage`, the footnote line looks correct, like on all the other pages

[image]

However, when i remove the `\clearpage`, the styling of last page of the bibliography is styled with `frontmatter`, despite the bibliography being rendered before the use of the `frontmatter` style.

I have tried `\cleardoublepage`, `\clearpage`, `\newpage`, `\pagebreak` at different places, before and after mainmatter, removing the chapter `Gutachten`, but at this point I am out of guesses. Has anyone seen this type of issue before? Or can you maybe recommend how I can approach debugging this?

Comment: Note that the code example might be slightly *too* minimal in some respect: It is missing the `\documentclass`, so we can't compile the example without guesswork. We also don't have the `\input`'d `.tex` files.

Comment: I have added the class that i use for this document, but the class is only documented in german. I also added the used packaged and settings that are relevant to page formatting. I removed the definition of frontmatter as its defined in the `jura` class. The `\input`s might as well be `\lipsum`, they contain only plain text with the `jura` classe's `\toc` and `\sub` commands

Comment: If the `\input` files might as well be `\lipsum`, please change your MWE to make them `\lipsum` and verify that the example compiles in an empty folder and still reproduces the issue. It would be quite unfortunate if we have to guess to make the MWE run, guess wrong and see something else than what you are seeing.

Comment: I'd replace `\usepackage{ngerman}` with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. The package `ngerman` hasn't been updated for years and is not compatible with some modern packages like `biblatex`.

Comment: Apologies. The updated code uses lipsum and does reproduce the issue out of the box

Comment: Your definition of \mainmatter is wrong. You shouldn't change the page numbering style without a previous \clearpage. The output with the \clearpage is actually the correct one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thats the way the `\mainmatter` command was before redefinition. It had a `\cleardoublepage` at the beginning. This however affects the placing of the footnote line on the first page of the Gutachten chapter

Comment: You are using geometry, better use its tools to change the geometry instead of use \voffset etc. And move the \pagenumbering behind the \clearpage.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the `\pagenumbering` is effectively after `\clearpage`. I just factored it out of the `\mainmatter` command to demonstrate how it affects my footnote line. When it comes to geometry, i have had some issues with it while using the `jura` class, what I have, I got after a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Sorry but it isn't obvious that it makes a difference if you change geometry values like e.g. \footskip on the current (before a \clearpage) or on the next page (after a \clearpage)? The jura.cls is very short, and basically a report.cls. I don't see why you should get problems with geometry, you could even drop the class without problems.

Comment: unrelated to your question but setting `\topskip=0pt` will make pages have a very inconsistent layout with the positions of baselines on each page varying depending on the text on the first line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have modified my `mainmatter` to use the geometry features, which actually went very smoothly, and that got rid of the weird issue. Most of the junk was replaces with simple `\newgeometry{left=6cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=2cm}`. Thank you a lot. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it :)